# Implementing tree like view in android

Tags: java, android, android-listview, treeview

I am trying to implement treeView in android using listView. There is ExpandableListView but it has only 2 levels. I don't want any constrain on levels.

ListItem is custom view having textview & button.

Also for every level I want to show title.

How to make it possible in android? Do you have any clue?

Thanx in advance.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/

Comment: @Sree thnx man for pointing out. It looks complicated. Is there any easy way to do things using native android API?

Comment: Native api only supports 2 levels

Comment: the second one is which i give, try the first one in native app

Answer (score 5):

Please check thease options like

[Treelist 1](http://androidcodesnips.blogspot.in/2011/09/three-level-expandable-list.html)

[Treelist 2](https://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/)

Comment: Can you include the relevant part of these posts here as the actual answer. If these links die the answer will become useless.

Comment: @nik Hi nik, thx for posting links. But 1st link is not much useful to me  as I already mentioned, there must not constrain on levels. Though it is really good attempt.. While for 2nd link, it sounds promising but I am getting issues when building app.

Comment: please post the issiues